# how to use name of user instead of user id

Tags: case, assignment-rules

here i am using user 18 digit id, but since from sandbox to development org. id can change, so i want to go by name of user which will not change. but i am not getting any name of user in drop down list. can anyone please help me out.

[image]

here i have tried with id in above image. is it possible to go with name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name field is not available, so you can do something like this:

[image]

Don't forget to add AND operator between two criteria.

Hope this helps.

Comment: and one more thing i would like to ask is can i use NOT operator in filter logic,,,, like --- NOT((Current User: First NameEQUALSPBI) AND (Current User: Last NameEQUALSDefault))

Comment: Yes you can use like NOT((Current User: First NameequalsTest) and (Current User: Last NameequalsFinal))

Comment: @Ratan are you available,,,,,,,,,,,,,,